# How to sub one Day from a Date String

Tags: java, date, groovy, jasper-reports

I have an SQL Parameter `Enddatum`, it is a String.
If I create a Textfield with the expression like:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( $P{Enddatum})
```

This works.

But I want to subtract one day from `Enddatum`. 
Like:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( $P{Enddatum}) - 1 DAY
```

But it doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse( $P{Enddatum}) - 1
```

Comment: **The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) Date, int**
I tryed it before.

Comment: Try executing `new Date() - 1` in the Groovy shell or Groovy console and you'll see that this operator is supported by `Date` for Groovy.

Comment: With Groovy it Works. Thanks a lot